# Ionic Splashscreen - How to remove fade?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have the cordova splashscreen plugin working in my ionic project - except that I don't want the spashscreen to fade in.  I've got the following in my config file but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />  
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
```

The splash screen still fades in for 3 seconds.  What am I missing?

I'm using Cordova version 5.4.1 and version 3.2.2 of the splashscreen plugin.

Comment: https://calendee.com/2015/03/03/polish-app-launch-with-cordova-splashscreen-plugin/ Check this

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000"/>
```

Add this in your config.xml. and adjust its value as required.
Earlier you were setting value of FadeSplashScreen to false , which was good because you did not want your splashscreen to fade in.But that was also the reason why any changes in your FadeSplashScreenDuration was not working.

Comment: I already have that in my config file. It's set to 1000.  But the delay is much longer than one second and it fades.  It seems this is just a bug in the cordova splash screen?